# SQL query duplicates elimination in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicate-data

A have two tables. In one are registrants, in other are custom fields and they are connected via id.

For example

Table 1

```
id   name    email
1    John    aaa@aaa.com
```

Table 2

```
field id    registrant id   value
1           1               Yes
2           1               Have dog
```

I want to connect these tables, and using this query

```
SELECT  `jos_eb_registrants`. * ,  `jos_eb_field_values`. * 
FROM jos_eb_registrants, jos_eb_field_values
WHERE  `jos_eb_registrants`.`event_id` =3
AND  `jos_eb_registrants`.`id` =  `jos_eb_field_values`.`registrant_id`
```

And getting this result

```
John aaa@aaa.com Yes
John aaa@aaa.com Have dog
```

I want this -

```
John aaa@aaa.com Yes Have dog
```

and separate collumns in csv with ;

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: How many matching rows can there be in Table2 for each of the row in Table1?

Comment: 7, but not all are required

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is the function `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT r.name, r.email,
       group_concat(`value` separator ' ') as `values`
FROM jos_eb_registrants r join
     jos_eb_field_values v
     on v.`id` =  v.`registrant_id`
WHERE r.`event_id` =3
group by r.name, r.email ;
```

This query also introduces table aliases, to make the query more readable.  It uses proper ANSI `join` syntax, and it adds an explicit `group by` (even though your example is only returning one row).

Comment: What means r and v. And i want all info from both tables,  not only email and name, but without duoble names.

Comment: @RokasKs . . . The `r` and `v` are table aliases, shorter table references.  If you have some other output in mind, then ask another question.  This answers seems to answer the query that you posted.

Comment: A have tables jos_eb_registrants and jos_eb_field_values , not r and v.

Comment: @RokasKs variable declaration is ones own choice, you can use your own convention replacing r and v

Comment: @RokasKs . . . Read about table aliases in this part of the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: No, im writing query in PHPMYADMIN. This answer turns RED in there, doesn't work.

Comment: @RokasKs . . . Probably because the word `values` is a reserved word.